# Get title from IDs in a string

Tags: functions, array, get-the-title

Im trying to get titles from IDs in string, but I'm getting stucked when I want to use get_the_title() function and receving error

> implode(): Invalid arguments passed

```
$act_name = explode(',', $unserialized['_gravity_form_lead']['9']);
$titles = implode(', ', get_the_title($act_name));
```

where `$unserialized['_gravity_form_lead']['9']` returns string like `3115,3116`

any ideas?

Comment: `get_the_title` accepts a single post ID and returns a string. you are trying to pass an array, and using the result as if it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

[get_the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) takes an int, not an array of ints, and therefore returns a string, not an array of strings.

So just break that bit out into a loop:

```
$titles = '';
foreach ($act_name as $act_name_item) {
  $titles .= ($titles ? ',' : '') . get_the_title ($act_name_item);
}
```